# Debian 10 on HP desktop with Geforce GTX 1650: stuck on black screen and cursor

Tags: drivers, debian, hp-pavilion, lxde, nouveau

I've installed Debian 10 Buster (10.2 LXDE to be exact but I've also tried Gnome and XCFE) on my latest desktop (HP Pavilion TP01-0012NP) but I can't reach the display manager's login prompt (X doesn't start, I guess). Windows 10 came pre-installed and works fine.

As for Debian, I can log in by going into terminal mode (Ctrl-Alt-F2) but have been unable to fix the problem, which appears to be related with the graphics card (Geforce GTX 1650) driver. I've tried installing the proprietary drivers, including from the buster-backports repository but so far no luck.

running `startx` from the terminal results in:

> xinit: giving up
>   xinit: unable to connect to x server: connection refused
>   xinit: server error

The tips provided in other threads (e.g., [debian 10 - hybrid graphics - how to use nvidia drivers instead of nouveau](https://superuser.com/questions/1484109/debian-10-hybrid-graphics-how-to-use-nvidia-drivers-instead-of-nouveau)) did not get me far. These included:
1) Blacklisting nouveau via the /etc/modprobe.d/ folder;
2) Installing the proprietary driver (from the non-free repositories, standard or backports versions);
3) Running nvidia-xconfig to generate a xorg.conf file and placing it the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder.

I've tried running a Ubuntu 18.04 live distro and it loads their display manager (unity?) but I get a low resolution so my guess is vesa is being used.

nvidia-detect says I should install nvidia-driver.

I don't think this desktop has a second graphics card (motherboard-based).

What else can I do? Thank you in advance.

FYI, I don't really need the graphics card for gaming or anything very demanding on that front.

Comment: According to [this site](https://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c06448992) it has an integrated GPU (not on the motherboard though, it's in the CPU, as always with Core processors). You can make use of it by blacklisting Nouveau and not installing the proprietary driver. This should at least get you to the desktop.

Comment: @K7AAY This is what I get by running startx from the command line as root: xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to x server: connection refused
xinit: server error

Comment: @gronostaj I did that but it didn't work. The problem, in this regard, may be that the integrated GPU (Intel UHD 630, apparently) is not found. For example, I am unable to identify the integrated GPU with lspci: only the nvidia graphics card shows up.

Comment: Did you install Unity in Debian 10? It's not included per https://www.debian.org/News/2019/20190706 . Also, Ubuntu abandoned Unity as its default desktop display manager in late 2017 and went back to GNOME3. You won't have Unity in Ubuntu 18.04 unless you installed it.

Comment: When you install a video card, the UHD graphics get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The HP Pavillon desktop you have does have integrated graphics in the i5-9400. But the UHD graphics are automatically disabled in the BIOS when a discrete card is installed. The simplest solution in your case is to remove the GTX 1650 from the computer. The computer will then boot using the onboard graphics. (UHD 630)

Install Debian 10 using the Intel drivers and then download the nvidia drivers using:

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver`

Once installed, shutdown and re-install the GTX 1650. Debian should load using the nvidia drivers that are installed. You can then configure using `nvidia-xconfig`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to boot Debian 10 without the GTX 1650 but not after reinstalling it. The Xorg.log says the nvidia kernel module failed to initialize. I used nvidia-xconfig to generate a .conf file, specified the BusID and placed the file in the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder. Any other suggestions? I think I'm going to try the experimental driver next.

Comment: Sid drivers didn't work either. I also noticed the following lines on the log files: 1) xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (operation not permitted); 2) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module; 3) error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error; 4)
Lockdown: ioperm is restricted; see https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I'm no pro with Debian sadly.... It's a known issue even with ubuntu right now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-430/+bug/1842740